# Linux mint acting weird after manual fsck for linux drive

Tags: linux-mint

My Linux Mint installed alongside windows (dual boot) wasn't booting and was giving the `(initramfs)` console so I ran a manual `fsck -y /dev/sda7`. Then when I booted back to Linux it gave two errors and the taskbar disappeared.

The first error is the same as this link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/89891/panel-encountered-a-problem-while-loading-clock-applet-factory-clockapplet and the other is the same but with the `wncklet` factory applet.

Any idea what I should to restore things before I ran the `fsck` or do I have to reinstall Mint again?

Comment: replace your hdd.

Comment: this should be the last resort right?

Comment: @IporSircer I would downvote your comment if I could. There's no evidence whatsoever in the question that indicates an impending disk failure.

Comment: JoeEhab12 did you get any messages or warnings from the `fsck` command? Generally it's a really bad idea to run `fsck -y` unless you know what you're doing. (Actually, let's generalise that to any invocation of `fsck`. Just don't do it.)